# Bootstrap 3. Responsive image with box + text (also responsive) in specific position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been researching how to do it but I have no clue.

I want to display a picture right after my navigation bar, centered in the web page and resposive to the size of the window. (I have achived that)

The problem is that I want to incorporate a translucent box with text inside. I want this box (with the text) to be responsive in the same way as the picture and also be located at the same position within the image (for instance 30px from the bottom of the pic and 30px from the left of the pictures).

```css
#main-picture{
 position:relative;
}

#main-picture #off{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 20%;
 right: 40%;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid" id="main-picture">
                      <img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/7d2c68e9ae46f5dfc10593129af90dab/tumblr_inline_mzze4zlPLM1re0xjv.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive center-block img-rounded">
                        <div class="col-md-4 img-rounded text-center" id="off">
                            <h3>Grand openning</h3>
                            <strong><h2>30% off</h2></strong>
                            <p>in all our products</p>
                        </div>
                     
                        
          </div>
```

I really don´t know how to do it. I've been trying different combinations but I don't achive what I want.

The effect that I want is similar to the "browse button" of this website https://www.danielladraper.com/

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you want it 30px from bottom and left of image,just set `bottom: 30px; left: 30px;`

Comment: That works only for the bottom. For the left it appears out of the image (that is centered in the website. I also want to know how can I make the box with the text responsive in the same way as the picture. Thank you so much for your reply dought.

Comment: You have left specified already, have you removed it?

Comment: Yes. I've changed the `top: 50%` and `left: 20%`; for  `bottom:30px; left: 30px;` and the box stays perfect at 30 px form the bottom of the image but it stays at 30px from the side of the website, not at 30 px form the side of the image